# XPages FilteringSelect not working - Unable to resolve constructor for: 'dojo.data.viewJsonService'

Tags: rest, dojo, xpages

I am trying to create a FilteringSelect element on a XPage. 
I want the field to be editable - be able to type to filter th values. 
The field values should be populated using a Rest service. 
I have successfully created a dojo.data.viewJsonService RestService.

My problem is the FilteringSelect field. 
The field behaves like a simple combobox and has no support for entering text to filter the values. Also, the FilteringSelect is always empty.

I have created a second FilteringSelect containing static values "djFilteringSelect1", that field also behaves like a simple combobox.

What am I doing wrong?

I have attached my code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" dojoForm="true"
    dojoParseOnLoad="true" dojoTheme="true">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="gridAsset">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"></xp:dojoModule>
    </xp:this.resources>

    <xe:restService id="objectRest" jsId="objectRestStore"
        pathInfo="objectRestPath">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewJsonService count="100" viewName="objects"
                defaultColumns="true" var="rowObjects"
                dojoType="dojo.data.viewJsonService">
                <xe:this.columns>
                    <xe:restViewColumn columnName="1"
                        name="GenObjekt">
                    </xe:restViewColumn>
                </xe:this.columns>
            </xe:viewJsonService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>

    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="djfsObject" trim="true"
        promptMessage="Search"
        invalidMessage="Not found, try again"
        store="objectRestStore" pageSize="10" searchAttr="GenObjekt"
        value="#{document1.ObjAnm}">
    </xe:djFilteringSelect>

    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Acai"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Apple"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Apricot"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Artichoke"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Asparagus"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Avocado"></xp:selectItem>
    </xe:djFilteringSelect>
</xp:view>
```

As pointed out by Per Henrik Lausten (thanks!); I am getting an error in the browser console. See below.

```
dojo/parser::parse() error Error: Unable to resolve constructor for: 'dojo.data.viewJsonService'
    at Object.<anonymous> (xspClientDojo.js:5)
    at Object.$DDSY_ [as map] (dojo.js:15)
    at Object.$DDSu_ [as _instantiate] (xspClientDojo.js:5)
    at xspClientDojo.js:5
    at _45c (dojo.js:15)
    at Promise.then._469.then (dojo.js:15)
    at Object.$DDSz_ [as parse] (xspClientDojo.js:5)
    at dojo.js:15
    at Function.$DDcf_ [as _onQEmpty] (dojo.js:15)
    at _3ba (dojo.js:15)
(anonymous) @ xspClientDojo.js:5
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console (both JS errors and 404 errors)?

Comment: Hi @PerHenrikLausten! Thanks for the reply! I am able to load the RestService going to https://[domain]/[path]/database.nsf/filteringSelect.xsp/objectRestPath but I do get an error on the page https://[domain]/[path]/database.nsf/filteringSelect.xsp ! 


'dojo/parser::parse() error Error: Unable to resolve constructor for: dojo.data.viewJsonService
    at Object.<anonymous> (xspClientDojo.js:5)
 ...
(anonymous) @ xspClientDojo.js:5'

Answer (score 0):

Cross reference with the REST service demo pages in XPages Extension Library demo database, packaged with the Extension Library download on OpenNTF. It looks like you're missing a dojo module in the resources area.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the demo database. I have already tried to  include the Dojo module o the XPage, but still get the same error. :/